# Find all visible selects with exactly 4 options

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

What is the shortest way to get all `selects` with exactly 4 `options`?

Otherwise I'll have to loop each `select` and get `$find('option').length == 4`

This does not seem to be working:

```
$.grep($("select:visible"), function () {
    return $(this).find('option').length == 4;
});
```

Comment: how about adding a class (i.e. opt4) when you create/populate them? then you can use just a class selector

Comment: @mike_t Oh sorry it is in the extension

Comment: Have you tried the [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method?

Comment: The accepted answer is probably best, but just to note, your solution using `$.grep()` doesn't work because the filtering function isn't bound to the element (to `this`) like it is with `filter()`. Instead it is passed as a parameter, so you would need to say `$.grep($("select:visible"), function (el) {
    return $(el).find('option').length == 4;
});`

Comment: @Rhumborl oh ok thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

The expression `:has(option:eq(3))` will target element which has alt-lest 4 `option` child element and expression `:not(:has(option:eq(4)))` will exclude element which have 5 `option` child.

```js
$("select:visible:has(option:eq(3)):not(:has(option:eq(4)))").css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

---

You can also use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
$("select:visible").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('option').length == 4;
}).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is also correct only problem is you need to wrap your select elements with some element to be able to make $.find function work.
For example

```
//Going to add a div to wrap all elememts    
var myDiv = $("<div><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select><div>");
$.grep(myDiv.find("select"),(el)=>$(el).find("option").length===4);
```